# MSBuild include all references in a directory

Tags: msbuild

I have an MSBuild script that builds a class library to a DLL.

In order to build, I need to include references to several dlls (i.e. log4net.dll, Elmah.dll etc etc).

At the moment, my build file includes the path to each of the dlls like this:

```
<Reference Include="C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\Debug\log4net.dll" />
<Reference Include="C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\Debug\Elmah.dll" />
<Reference Include="C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll" />

etc. etc. etc.
```

Then, in the Target, I have my CSC:
    References="@(Reference)"

This is becoming quite tedious. What I would like to do is put all dependent dll's into a single directory someplace on the filesystem, and then pass a single to reference to the directory and MSBuild would use and required dll's contained in that directory.

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you already try simply use a wildcard in your include: `<Reference Include="C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\Debug\*.dll" />` ?

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly. Can you put this in as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To include all items from one folder, simply use a wildcard in your reference include statement:

```
<Reference Include="C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\Debug\*.dll" />
```

You can even use recursive wildcards such as `C:\Projects\MillinCommon\Trunk\bin\**\*.dll` to include from a folder and all its subfolders.

See [MSBuild Items - Using Wildcards to Specify Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_Wildcards) for details.